# access remote url from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know it's possible to load a webpage inside eclipse, but this isn't what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is to load raw data (json or xml) from a remote url via http. For example the plugin could request data for bugs with status unresolved. That query will go to the url which will return data. My plugin needs to then read this data. So any suggestions what I need to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new URL(url).openStream() will open an input stream. you an read data from this stream.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)(Representational state transfer).